# How to decode urllib response data

Tags: javascript, web, urllib

I'm use urllib craw a https web,
**the response_header are:**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Content-type: application/octet-stream
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Wed, 07 Nov 2018 07:01:00 GMT
Server: lighttpd
```

**response data are:** 
[response data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6GGb.jpg)

**The web display are:**
[response display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BGxK.jpg)

I know the content type **application/octet-stream** are not general encoding,but there must be some web js decode those response data,Does anyone know how to find the decode code from the web js or find out which web js file use the response data

Comment: what kind of resource is it? image? archive? or what?

Comment: The web display are parameters table  and some icon image

Comment: table? xlsx? or image?

Comment: Like xlsx in tablecontainer ,but I cannot use beautifulsoup to find the table

Comment: just save output to file and check locally with different apps

Comment: Different apps?which app?chrome or web javascript

Comment: just try to manually save output to xls file using notepad or something. And try to open it in Excel.

Comment: On the table bottom have a export button,but that not what I want,I'm crawling this web ,I need the way that decode those response data automatically and send my database,not save the output to file manually.